# Binding values and Parameters in PDO Prepared Statements :PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

As `PDOStatement::`execute documentation says, "All values are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`.
So I have following questions

1)Suppose I have a variable `$_SESSION['id']=2` and a query

```
$sql='select * from articles where id=?';
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($_SESSION['id']));
```

When I execute the statements,it executes successfully.
It signifies that it passes variable as an integer .Does it do automatic casting or it violates the documentation statement?

2)Suppse I have another query

```
select * from articles where id=? and category=?
```

Now here first parameter is `int` and last parameter is `string` so when I bind parameters `$query->bindValue(2, $_GET['category'],PDO::PARAM_STR);` do I need to specify `PDO::PARAM_STR` or I can rely on the default implementation that it is considered as `string` by default as the documentation says.

3)I want to specify table name from `$_GET['category']` into the query but I get the following format of the string(notice the quotes around table name) and hence SQL error.How can I correct it?

```
select * from 'article'...........
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1) When I execute the statements,it executes successfully. It
>   signifies that it passes variable as an integer .Does it do automatic
>   casting or it violates the documentation statement?

No, it does pass the parameter as string. MySQL is casting it back to an int transparently because the column is an int value, which in this case has no side effects.

> 2) do I need to specify `PDO::PARAM_STR` or I can rely on the default
>   implementation that it is considered as string by default as the
>   documentation says.

Unless the API ever changes, it's pretty sure that it's bound as a string if the documentation says so. I doubt the API will change that any time soon, or at all. I might still explicitly bind it as string, just to make it extremely clear to a reader of the source code.

> 3) I want to specify table name from $_GET['category'] into the query
>   ...

You cannot. You can only "placehold" *values*, not identifiers or other structural elements of the query. Parameterised statements are explicitly to separate between the *structure* of the query and the *values* dynamically interpolated into it; if you could dynamically interpolate structural elements there'd be no point to this separation.

Comment: In the last question I want to change the table name dynamically,which I am getting through `GET`.Isn't there any way to create such query with dynamic table names.That was the purpose of last question

Comment: You'll have to do it the good old way: `"SELECT * FROM $table ..."`. You must keep a *whitelist* of allowable table names! Check if `$table` is one of a few allowed values before inserting it into the query this way.

Comment: @InsaneCoder if you need that, it means your database design is *insane* and you better make it *normal*